# Changing Disk Size of VM before VM installation using qemu kvm

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, kvm

[VM Disk Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEe8f.png)

I wanted to change Disk Size upto 20G before vm Installation. The image already has Virtual size of 50G.

Answer (score 0):

First, You should consider trying to compress the disk size.

```
sudo qemu-img -O qcow2 vmf5.img vmf5-compact.qcow2
```

If you really need those disk spaces, what you need to do:

```
sudo qemu-img resize /var/lib/libvirt/images/vmf5.img 20G
```

There is a document about [qemu-img](https://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img)